# Splitting a string containing both characters and numbers on the basis of space

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to add items to a `listView` from an `array of strings` using indexes.
Following is my code:

```
using (StringReader tr = new StringReader(Mystring))
{
    string Line;
    while ((Line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] temp = Line.Split(' ');
        listview1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(temp[1], temp[3]));
    }
}
```

But it gives an `index out of bound error`.

When I do not use index as

```
listview1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(temp));
```

it works fine and adds the contents of the array to the listView.

And it also adds zero index string to the listView. For one, two or other indexes it gives the same error.

Please any one tell me how I can add only my required strings to listView using index or any other method.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `temp[1],temp[3]` are the second and forth elements of the array. Do you actually have 4 elements in the array?

Comment: Yeah I agree with Oded, you might mean temp[0], temp[2]

Comment: What do the lines you are trying to add look like? Did you debug through the exception to see what the value of `temp` is when the exception in thrown?

Comment: Yes I have more than four elements in array

Comment: Debugging would help in this case.

Comment: @ghulam_ali no, if so the exception couldn't be thrown.

Comment: You should provide sample data in your `Mystring`.

Comment: It looks like the [`ListViewItem Constructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2faa998d.aspx) that your are using  `ListViewItem(string,string)` is designed to add a new item + the name of the Image from the associated ImageList Control. We actually need to see a couple lines of your text file to see exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string ends with a line break, you will get an empty string as the last line. Skip any empty lines:

```
using (StringReader tr = new StringReader(Mystring)) {
  string Line;
  while ((Line = tr.ReadLine()) != null) {
    if (Line.Length > 0) {
      string[] temp = Line.Split(' ');
      listview1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(temp[1], temp[3]));
    }
  }
}
```

Additionaly, you could check the length of the array after splitting, but I assume that if there is anything at all in the line, it would be correct.

Comment: this looks like a good answer which may help the OP, however there hasn't any response from the OP. :)